# Can the anti-whale tile be used to defend against the giant squid?

Tags: escape-from-atlantis

In *Survive: Escape from Atlantis* with the giant squid mini-expansion, the whales and squids are treated as being roughly the same critter.  Does this mean that the anti-whale tiles can be used to defend against marauding squids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can use the anti-whale tiles to defend against the giant squid.**

Although I was unable to find a FAQ for the game on Stronghold-Games website, [Kevin Nesbitt](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/11028/kevin-nesbitt) who is a credited designer of one of Survives other mini expansions [said the following](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/6100496#6100496):

> The Giant Squid and Whale are meant to be largely interchangeable, at least in how they are brought into and out of play. Since a player must select either a whale OR a Giant Squid, they may also choose to harpoon *either* by play of the defensive whale tile (but only one "harpooning" per tile, please!)